# Changing the SelectedIndex of Multiple Select Listbox to the last selected item

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, listbox

Refering to a C#, .net, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Lisbox which has a multiple select option true and needs to do a postback every time selected index changes.

Problem is, the [SelectedIndex / SelectedItem / SelectedValue] is always on the value of the **1st selected item**. Clicking on the second item, third item, does not change the SelectedIndex, causing the listbox to reload and scroll to the highest selected item position.

Comment: The closest solution I've got is a global javascript var to track the last clicked item. But that is not ideal, on prerender, the listbox jumps to the top most selected item (before any javascript can kick in).

Comment: Also...when I debug the SelectedIndexChange function, there is a list of selected items cached, but no indication of which is the last one added.

Comment: I guess there is no real way of doing this in back-end while still using the postback is true option for Listbox. Closing this thread if that is so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this as far this control is concerned.

Comment: bullshit :) see my reply. I haven't tried it, but in principle it should work. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Brandon - can you share the code where you are loading the listbox. Below are few probable reasons for ListBox not to hold its selection:

1. Reloading list box in post back (after post data has been processed)
2. Dynamically loading list box late in page life cycle so that there is no chance to process post back data
3. Dynamically loading list box (perhaps in templated parent) so that its Client ID changes (or specifically, ClientID is different when post data processing happens).

Comment: The Listbox is holding its selection(s), I just don't know which is the last clicked-on item amongst the items.

Comment: @Brandon, understood your issue. Possible solution could be tracking previously selected items to determine the one that has changed now and then using java-script to scroll the control. IMO, better solution would be to consider some alternate UI - for example, having two side by side list boxes - one showing available options and other showing selected options with left/right arrow buttons to select/deselect.

Comment: unfortunately I've considered both options. The Listbox is a sort list with delete options, so breaking it into 2 seperate listboxes wouldn't be applicable. The javascript option works but is after pre-render, so there will be a possible jump up then down in the listbox if I got one item selected on top, then a later one at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The SelectedIndex will always point to the lowest selected index. 
The definition of the ListBox.SelectedIndex property:

Gets or sets the **lowest** ordinal index of the selected items in the list.

Manually setting the selectedindex property will de-select all other selections, and I am pretty sure that there is no way (in .net code) to scroll down to a particular selection.

I don't have a clear picture of what you're trying to do, but perhaps you can capture all selected indexes by using the GetSelectedIndices ListBox function, and compare against the previously captured selected indexes to determine the most recent selected item.

Comment: I can capture all selected indexes.. but not sure how to capture previously selected ones before the ListBox click+postback.

Comment: You're right in that manually setting the SelectedIndex will kill the multiple selected items. So I'm guessing there is no solution to this problem. It is irritating when I have a really long listbox, and clicking on a bottom item will cause a postback and position unto any selected item higher in the selected items list, thereby possibly hiding the most recently clicked item.

Comment: Maybe you can use a second list box to show only the selected items. With each SelectedIndexChanged event, you can rebuild the second list.

Answer (score 0):

Brandon Make sure that you don't populate the ListBox every time the page loads

Comment: As I've mentioned as a pre-qualifier. The postback option (and hence auto population) is necessary and set to true for the solution.

Comment: I might need to refactor the whole listbox and those controls that depend on the auto-postback...

Comment: When i Faced that problem before it was in the postback , as every time the page posted back i repopulated my list box.

Answer (score 0):

This is strictly a scrolling problem.

To explicitly control the scroll value of a ListBox (or any element for that matter), you need to use JavaScript to set the [scrollTop](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Properties/scrollTop.htm) property:

```
document.all.getElementById("elementID").scrollTop = VALUE.
```

So alter the JavaScript handler that does the post-back for your list box, which looks like "javascript:__doPostBack(...".  Replace that with a call to a custom function that grabs the current scrollTop value, saves it to a hidden variable, then calls __doPostBack as it was originally supposed to.

After the round trip, that hidden value should persist back to the client, so in a JavaScript page load event, simply read that hidden value and reapply it to the scrollTop of your list box.  Your list box will then be scrolled exactly where it was before the post back occurred.